# What is the role of the character x in this sql injection?

Tags: sql-injection

`admin'xor(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(5),0)xor'z`

I tried this payload on my local database and removed the `x` like this `admin'or(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(5),0)or'z'` and it works fine

Why do we added the `x`? Is it to bypass some defense mechanism?

Comment: Who said you needed the x?

Answer (score 1):

`admin'xor(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(5),0)xor'z` is a query to a time-based blind sql injection.

`or` and `xor` are both logical operators.
The difference between both is shown in this Image.
[image: logical operators]

<sub>[Source](http://john-home.iptime.org:8085/xe/index.php?mid=board_XylG00&m=1&document_srl=3124)</sub>

Since the only purpose of this payload is to check for a vulnerability by checking whether the `if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(5),0)` gets executed or not, and even if something gets compared, both other conditions are presumably false, so using `or` or `xor` does not make a difference and would return the same result.

Why is `xor` used then?

I cannot give you an answer that is for 100% the exact reason. My guess is that it is related to a Web Application Firewall.
Often a Web Application Firewall (WAF) is used, trying to detect SQL injections. The WAF filters for keywords like `SELECT`, `AND`, `OR` etc.
The `xor` is used to evade a unproperly configured WAF that only filters for the Keyword `or` but not `xor`.

It is also possible that the payload is designed to test other values in follow up queries, where it could make a difference whether you use `or` and `xor`.

Long answer short, in this case it does not make a difference whether you use `or` or `xor`, but it could be related to a WAF and make a difference when the query gets modified.